# Best way to output a binary sequence in Python

Tags: python

I have a binary sequence, for example: `10010111010101`. I need to output this sequence to a file and then read it later but I want it to be compressed as much as possible, what is the easiest way to do this?

I have tried to take every 8 bits (byte) in the sequence together and output the byte value and then when I read it later, I cut it bit by bit, is there an easier way? or a module that does this readily?

Comment: What do you actually have? A string with ones and zeroes? Is there some code you could post for context?

Comment: I wouldn't aim for compressing 'as much as possible' as Kolmogrov complexity is uncomputable, there's a tradeoff between time spent compressing and the compression ratio you'll achive.

Comment: @khelwood I have an array of ones and zeroes, I can construct a string or anything else, it doesn't matter

Comment: If you have a string of ones and zeroes, you can parse it as a binary int, and then you simply have an int.

Comment: @JeffLinahan I know it is time consuming but the bit stream size isn't that big and I can afford time over space

Comment: @khelwood What about overflow?

Comment: @YoussefWalid In Python 3 ints are arbitrarily large; they don't overflow.

Comment: @khelwood Didn't know that! thanks a lot

Comment: "an array of ones and zeroes" - a built-in list? A numpy `np.array`? Something else? Where did the data come from? Please *show some actual code*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel A built-in list, but what does it matter? I can simply parse it to anything I would need.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

The best textual encoding for binary data is either base64 or ascii85.

ASCII85

```py
import base64
import sys

# Length of the binary string in bytes (32 bytes will let you have a 256 digit binary character stream)
# Keep it as low as possible to save space
length = 32

binary_string = input('Enter binary string : ')
integer = eval('0b'+binary_string)
data = integer.to_bytes(length, sys.byteorder, signed=False)

print(base64.a85encode(data).decode('utf-8'))
```

Base64

```py
import base64
import sys

# Length of the binary string in bytes (32 bytes will let you have a 256 digit binary character stream)
# Keep it as low as possible to save space
length = 32

binary_string = input('Enter binary string : ')
integer = eval('0b'+binary_string)
data = integer.to_bytes(length, sys.byteorder, signed=False)

print(base64.b64encode(data).decode('utf-8'))
```

WARNING: Typically `sys.byteorder` is little-endian, so you might run into problems when you try to load up the file.

Comment: You can parse a string as a binary int with `int(binary_string, 2)`. You don't need to resort to `eval`.

Comment: What if the binary string starts with a '0'? wouldn't that get lost in the encoding? example: `000011`

Comment: No, because the length of the string is fixed, here 32 bytes. Change the value of that if you need longer strings. If you try to convert more than that you will get an exception

Comment: Your binary string is actually just padded with zeroes to the length, so `11100001111` becomes `00000 11100001111` for a 2 byte length.